# Why do many Web sites miscalculate my current time?

Tags: time, timezone, web

I am using Debian. My clock shows the current time. I set the BIOS to Greenwich, but then the time is adjusted to the current time zone. But when I visit many Web sites, they think I'm visiting from a much earlier time in the day. Some stores, for instance, say "Store will open at 6 am" instead of the usual "Will close at 7 pm" warning. And some Web site where I post homework to students, I choose a due date of "9 pm" for the assignment, but my students see "3 pm" as the due date.

Where in Linux are Web sites getting the wrong time off my computer?

Comment: In the browser console, what does `Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone` output?

Comment: What is the output of `date;date -u`?

Comment: What's the output of `timedatectl`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you have some kind of browser fingerprinting protection enabled. For example in Firefox it's enabled by `privacy.resistFingerprinting = true` & `privacy.trackingprotection.fingerprinting.enabled = true` settings in `about:config`. Or an add-on you've added for protection has enabled something equivalent.

Time zone is one of the fingerprints used to track. So masking it helps avoid tracking. Having BIOS to UTC is not related, since you've properly set your time zone.